# WPF combobox doesn't change SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So I have a custom class for my object like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(string name)
    {
        this.AName = name;
    }

    public string AName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a list of these in my ViewModel:

```
public List<ClassA> ObjectList
{
    get { return _myobjects; }
    set
    {
        _myobjects = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ObjectList");
    }
}
```

Now, I have a combobox in my window with this list as its `Itemssource`:

```
<ComboBox Width="150" x:Name="cboObjectList"   
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectList}" DisplayMemberPath="AName"/>
```

The problem is that when I select any item in the combobox, The `SelectedIndex` property is always = -1 and also the `SelectedItem` is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are able to see all of the items in the combobox correct? If so, how are you determining that the SelectedIndex property is always = -1 and the SelectedItem is null?

Comment: I think @Sudsy1002 has it. This sounds like a life cycle issue.

Comment: Are you binding the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem to a property?  I mean it sounds like you are but the code doesn't show that.

Comment: change NotifyPropertyChanged("Builders"); to NotifyPropertyChanged("ObjectList");

Comment: @Sudsy1002 I have a button with a click event that reads the selected value of that combobox and it shows null. When I debug it gets me SelectedIndex = -1

Comment: @iMortalitySX Nope I'm not binding it to anything because I don't need the binding I just need to read the selected value

Comment: @Jon That was just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the cause of the cause of the problem. There was an old line of code where I programmatically set the SelectedIndex to -1 :)